# Fetch Device IP Addresses/MAC address of devices connected to a LAN

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, networking, ip-address

Currently I am wondering how I would go about implementing a fetch request to a local wireless network (router) to obtain all devices currently connected to a currently connected LAN....

So I've done some research and apparently 'nmap' is a terminal/commandprompt command that returns connected devices to a local wireless network, with some parameters that need to be inputted into the nmap command.

I found an iPhone app that does what I'm trying to do... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fip-network-scanner-lite%2Fid335517828%3Fmt%3D8&ei=qhHfUbDpJ4GkigKClIHYCg&usg=AFQjCNFMDPn5H8TbDw54-zYDYJ9iezRXpA&sig2=QN42a5w-MgClO5BvBUoDGw

It scanns for devices on a currently connected WiFi network and displays all devices connected to such network... I am attempting to do the same but am stuck on where to start...

Anyone have any ideas? I am trying to do this for iOS..

Comment: did you figure out this question already?

Comment: I haven't but I feel that looking at the answered post can put you on the right track... Not entirely sure though

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could do a broadcast ping, ala:

```
$ ping -b 192.168.0.255
```

using the Apple [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) for ping.

But I have not tried it.